# "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer" intermittently this error is occurring for Ubuntu 14.04.5

Tags: ssh

While trying to access my Ubuntu VM, I am facing intermittent `ssh` connectivity issue. Please note this is an intermittent issue.I have checked `/etc/hosts` , `hosts.allow` , `hosts.deny` files as per available posts related to this issue but could not see any wrong entries over these config files.
Please find the debug o/p as below

### O/p when the issue is occurring

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.6, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "10.10.50.26" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.10.50.26 [10.10.50.26] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file pem.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file pem.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.6
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

### O/p when its working

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.6, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "10.10.50.26" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.10.50.26 [10.10.50.26] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file pem.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file pem.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 10.10.50.26:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
```

Could you please help to fix this issue? Thanks in Advance

Comment: hi ajith, were you able to get this resolved. im getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked here: https://superuser.com/questions/856989/ssh-error-ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer .

tl;dr Check your Firewall and make sure you are not getting blocked.

I recently ran into this issue. I later found out that my firewall was seeing the traffic as an ssh brute force attack and blocked it.
After adding a firewall rule it was resolved.

Note:

1. My ssh traffic came from Jenkins. The firewall was reading all ssh traffic from that server as an ssh brute force attack and started blocking requests.
2. This issue arose when our on premise Jenkins server started talking to our newly cloud hosted source management server.